# Is it possible to set WebTrends DCS ID dynamically in Swift project

Tags: iphone, swift, analytics, ios9.1, webtrends

I am working on iOS application. I need to implement WebTrends analytics in my iOS application. 
Can I set WT_DCSID dynamically after load data from server.Because I have got WT_DCSID from server not static.
Can I do it or not. Please suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plese take a look at [advance configuration link](http://help.webtrends.com/en/ios/docs/public_guides/Advanced-Configuration-Guide.html).
Based on this doc, you would use something like:

WTDataCollector.sharedCollector().setValue("dcsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx", kWTConfigDCSID, persists:true)

You still need to set a default wt_dc_dcsid in the webtrends.plist as this is what is read when Webtrends loads it's configuration. You can simply overwrite it after that point programmatically.

Thank you,